# Linkedin - Preview image doesn't show

Tags: node.js, image, linkedin-api, sharing

Been going round and round on this one. Not a new issue but struggling to identify exactly why LinkedIn doesn't like my images and everyone else does. Facebook and twitter show ok with it

At first thought might be meta issue or cache issue (am familiar with the clear method) or image requirements stated by LinkedIn but ruled all that out. The ssl is a free one but soon to be using a wildcard as facebook didn't like it to see if that has any effect.

The image server uses node js express to deliver static files.

If I just share the image, that shows an error of: "Cannot display preview. You can post as is, or try another link." which points to the server and image to me instead of the website.

The site and images are on different servers with different setups.

Main url is https://rocketthomerentals.com/property/5-bed-house-to-rent-in-newcastle-under-lyme/102750000371

with the image of 
http://media.estateapps.co.uk/487/102750000371_IMG_371_1_large.jpg

Anything else I can try? Should be getting the new wildcard SSL sorted early next week but posting here to see if there is anything else I am missing I can try to see if that has any effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's gone around in circles about this issue, was resolved by defining the content type as image, it was missing from the server config.